# Python: call parent instancemethod

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism, python-2.x

For example, I have next code:

```
class Dog:
    def bark(self):
        print "WOOF"

class BobyDog( Dog ):
    def bark( self ):
        print "WoOoOoF!!"

otherDog= Dog()
otherDog.bark() # WOOF

boby = BobyDog()
boby.bark() # WoOoOoF!!
```

BobyDog is a child of Dog and have overrided instancemethod "bark".

How I can refer to parent method "bark" from instance of class "BobyDog"?

In other words:

```
class BobyDog( Dog ):
    def bark( self ):
        super.bark() # doesn't work
        print "WoOoOoF!!"

otherDog= Dog()
otherDog.bark() # WOOF

boby = BobyDog()
boby.bark()
# WOOF
# WoOoOoF!!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **call** the `super()` function, and pass in the current class (`BobyDog`) and `self`:

```
class BobyDog( Dog ):
    def bark( self ):
        super(BobyDog, self).bark()
        print "WoOoOoF!!"
```

More importantly, you need to base `Dog` on `object` to make it a new-style class; `super()` does not work with old-style classes:

```
class Dog(object):
    def bark(self):
        print "WOOF"
```

With these changes the call works:

```
>>> class Dog(object):
...     def bark(self):
...         print "WOOF"
... 
>>> class BobyDog( Dog ):
...     def bark( self ):
...         super(BobyDog, self).bark()
...         print "WoOoOoF!!"
... 
>>> BobyDog().bark()
WOOF
WoOoOoF!!
```

In Python 3, old-style classes have been removed; everything is new-style, and you can omit the class and `self` parameters from `super()`.

In old-style classes, the only way to call the original method is by referring directly to the unbound method on the parent class and manually pass in `self`:

```
class BobyDog( Dog ):
    def bark( self ):
        BobyDog.bark(self)
        print "WoOoOoF!!"
```